# Angular 2 Directives and DOM manipulation

Tags: angular

Struggling to find a solution for this.

I am trying to replace the innerHtml of an element with html that was generated from another library. Seems simple enough but not with Angular 2 of course. I am basically wrapping google-prettify-code script in an Angular 2 app directive.

in the component html that contains my prettify directive I want to add something like this.

```
<pre dg-prettify>
    &lt;div class=&quot;foobar&quot;&gt;
     &lt;div&gt;Hello World&lt;/div&gt;
   &lt;/div&gt;
</pre>
```

Then inside my prettify directive I need to take the innerHtml of the pre tag and pass it to the external library to be processed. I will get back a decoded html structure that then needs to be injected into the innerHtml of the pre tag replacing it's original content .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the component HTML contents are static, something like this should work:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[dg-prettify]'
})
export class Prettify {
  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    let innerHTML = this.elRef.nativeElement.innerHTML;
    console.log(innerHTML);
    // call 3rd-party library
    let newHtml = someExternalLibraryFunction(innerHtml);
    this.elRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = newHtml;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<pre dg-prettify>
    &lt;div class=&quot;foobar&quot;&gt;
     &lt;div&gt;Hello World&lt;/div&gt;
   &lt;/div&gt;
</pre>`,
  directives: [Prettify]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() { console.clear(); 
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/esTL8CylpNl4MnDCn4h7?p=preview)</kbd>

If the component HTML content is dynamic, then pass that content to the directive as a string input property, and implement [lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) `ngOnChange()` to update the innerHTML whenever the content changes.

Comment: I think I tried a similar approach unsuccessfully, I thought the ElementRef may have been read only so I moved on. I did not use the let keyword so maybe that is where I went wrong, I will try this approach again. Thanks

Comment: Ok, total brain fart on my end. I was setting innerHtml and not innerHTML. I had the wrong case and it kicked my butt all day long! Thanks a bunch...

Comment: @JBeckton, I really wish they had named that property innerHtml too.